# How do I check the values retrieved from this Linq query as .ToLower()?

Tags: c#, linq, indexof

This is my code:

```
DataRow r = VirtualTable
  .AsEnumerable()
  .FirstOrDefault(tt => (tt.Field<string>("Column1") == value1) ||
                        (tt.Field<string>("Column1") == value2));
```

This code retrieves a data row whose 'Column1' matches a given string. I then check this against a bool if statement. However, though I can change my string's capitalization, I don't know how to handle it with the value Linq gives me. Still learning linq, so I don't know my way around it yet.

In short, I have the string "Red box" in the table, but want it to be read as "red box" so it will match my internal string of the same value.

Additionally, I was trying to retrieve the `IndexOf` the row this query gives me, but I'm always retrieving a -1 even if it finds a match.

Here's the code to retrieve it:

```
int SelectedIndex = VirtualTable.Rows.IndexOf(r);
```

Comment: `.FirstOrDefault(tt => (tt.Field<string>("Column1").ToLower() == value1)`

Comment: why not use `tt.Field<string>("Column1").ToLower() == "red box"`?

Comment: What is `VirtualTable`? Why are you using `AsEnumerable()`? If you used EF, the string comparison would be case-insensitive. Right now, you can use `String.Equals` with  a case-insensitive option

Comment: Try `string.Equals(tt.Field<string>("Column1"), value1, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, VirtualTable is just a DataTable. I'll try string.Equals.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that, @HimBromBeere. I should've read more into it.

Comment: @HimBromBeere In this case it doesn't matter at all. A DataTable is already in memory. In order to use LINQ to Datasets, you *have* to use `AsEnumerable`. This won't load anything more into memory

Comment: Try this to get index : DataRow r = VirtualTable
  .AsEnumerable()
  .Select((x,i) => new { abc = x, index = i}).Where(tt => (abc.tt.Field<string>("Column1") == value1) ||
                        (abc.tt.Field<string>("Column1") == value2))
  .Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault().index);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `string.Equals` to ignore case and overload `Select` to get row's index:

```
   var row = VirtualTable
     .AsEnumerable()
     .Select((tt, index) => new {
        value = tt.Field<string>("Column1"),
        index = index})
     .FirstOrDefault(item => 
        string.Equals(item.value, value1, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) ||
        string.Equals(item.value, value2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

   // If we have the row found, we can get
   if (row != null) {
     var r = row.value;              // value, e.g. "bla-bla-bla"
     int selectedIndex = row.index;  // as well as its index, e.g. 123 
     ... 
   }
```

Comment: This did the trick, thanks! I'll test the effectiveness of String.Equals on my data.

Comment: @Arvayne: you are welcome! Since `string.Equals` has been *specially designed* to test strings for equality it has a very good chance to be the most efficient approach.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [String.Equals(string,StringComparisonOption)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c64xh8f9(v=vs.110).aspx) to compare two strings using case-insensitive comparison. This avoids generating yet-another-temporary-string as `ToLower()` would do, eg:

```
tt.Field<string>("Column1").Equals(value1,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
```

or

```
tt.Field<string>("Column1").Equals(value1,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Make sure you use the appropriate comparison option. Different cultures have different casing rules. Ordinal is the fastest option as it compares strings using binary rules.